# PushSharp Push doesn't process queue until stop

Tags: ios, c#-4.0, apple-push-notifications, pushsharp

PushSharp only processes the queue when stop is called. Does anyone have an idea how often push sharp will process the queue or flush it? I don't want to have to call stop and start every time I want to send a notification to conserve resources.

```
            pushService = new PushService();
            pushService.StartApplePushService(new ApplePushChannelSettings(prod,  cert.InputStream.ReadToEnd(), passConfig.Value));
  pushService.QueueNotification(
                NotificationFactory.Apple().ForDeviceToken("mydeviceid").WithAlert("Notifications Started!").WithSound("default").WithBadge(7));


            pushService.StopAllServices(true);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm a complete and utter idiot...

The main thread was completing execution before the queue timer could process the notification. StopAllServices forced the thread to wait... Maybe this will help someone else.